# No translations for `Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page`

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, language, inline-translations

I am using Magento 2.3.1

I can not load translations for text `Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.` shows occasionally on frontend.

Of course I add translations for language .csv placed in theme.
I also tried add translation to specific modules.

Comment: The exact phrase is Invalid <Form Key. Please refresh the page.> aren't you missing the dot?

Comment: nope, There is dot in csv. I just miss it when copied here

Comment: Are your other translations working ?

Comment: Yes, other translations works fine

Comment: Is this got resolved ?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a Magento CORE Issues, Reported at: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/27889 and FIXed within Magento 2.4.0++. Release Notes: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/release-notes/release-notes-2-4-0-open-source.html:

```
The Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page text string on the login page is now translated as expected.
```